# playing Audio from BLOB field of a Table of a SQLite DB

Tags: android, database, audio, blob, playback

I store my audio file to a sqlite database (as BLOB) and now I want to gain it from db and also play it when a button clicked. 
my db table has three field: rowID, image, audio
that in each row of my table, an image and an audio stored (as BLOB).

I try this but did not work for me:

```
byte[] byteAudio2 = null;

Cursor cur1 = db.query("audiofromdb_tbl", null, null, null, null, null, null);

cur1.moveToFirst();
byteAudio2 = cur1.getBlob(cur1.getColumnIndex("audio"));        
File tempWav = null;
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tempWav);
    fos.write(byteAudio2);
fos.close();

MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
mp.setDataSource(fos.getFD());
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

try something like this :

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
int size = 0;
ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteAudio2); 

while ((size = byteArrayStream.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) > 0) {
    fos.write(buffer, 0, size);
}
```

[]

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps too late but if someone needs it.

This works for me:

```
 File file;
 FileOutputStream fos;

 byteaudio = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex("sonido"));

 try {

        file = File.createTempFile("sound", "sound");
        fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        fos.write(byteaudio);
        fos.close();

        Log.d("File", file.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
mp = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), Uri.fromFile(file));
            mp.start();
```